# How to load logback.xml file from external path, other than resource folder

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm not able to print the slf4j log message. The controller is not loading logback.xml file. I searched on net I found that

```
static 
{ 
    System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile",     "D:/RxBDataFeeder/RxBDataFeeder/config/logback.xml");
}
```

This code is also not working.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass the logback config file as a param while starting the app as shown below.

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=path/logback.xml MyApp
```

if you want to automatically reconfigure it when you change something it your logback.xml then use the below in logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" > 
  ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

`logback.xml` is ment to be loaded from external resources as a standalone file, so sysadmin can change logging settings without recompiling the code.

LoggerFactory automaticly picks up any `logback.xml` file from the classpath, so in order to use external file, add its containing directory to a runtime classpath.

How to set runtime classpath is described here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: can u give some hint, how to add logback.xml file into classpath. I've added logback.xml file to classpath, but it is showing error. Archive for required library: 'logback-test.xml' in project 'RxBDataFeeder' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file RxBDataFeeder  Build path Build Path Problem

Answer (score 0):

This will fix:

```
$javapath -jar $jarname --logging.config=/path/to/logback.xml
```